# Types of convergences of random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have seen different types of convergence among random variables

1. Almost sure.
2. In mean.
3. In probability.
4. In distribution.

What are the differences between them, I'm looking for a more intuitive answer.
In addition, every type of convergence has a particular mode to check the convergence. I realized for example, that to check convergence in mean and probability you have to use a lot of inequalities.
Is there advices to check every convergence?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1170559/36150) is related

Comment: Thank you. I will give a try.