# Does the following sequence of R.V. converge (L^1 and a.s.)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, pointwise-convergence

Consider the sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ on the probability space $((0,1],\mathcal{B}((0,1]))$ defined by $$\begin{align*} X_1(\omega) &:= 1_{\big(\frac{1}{2},1 \big]}(\omega) \\ X_2(\omega) &:= 1_{\big(0, \frac{1}{2}\big]}(\omega) \\ X_3(\omega) &:= 1_{\big(\frac{3}{4},1 \big]}(\omega) \\ X_4(\omega) &:= 1_{\big(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4} \big]}(\omega)\\ &\vdots \end{align*}$$

I need to show whether this sequence converges in $L^1$ and a.s. but I am not sure about what $X_5$, $X_6$, $X_7$ ...looks like. Can you help me?

Comment: This looks like a standard example: I assume the pattern is supposed to be that on each round $k$ we chop the unit interval into $2^k$ equal sized disjoint subintervals. Then each round $k$ has $2^k$ sub-rounds where we individually consider each subinterval associated with round $k$. If you put all the subrounds in order one after the other you can enumerate them, obtaining a sequence of intervals as is done above.

Comment: Thank you. So we have $X_5=(1/4,1/2]$,$X_6=(0,1/4]$,$X_7=(7/8,1]$,$X_8=(6/8,7/8]$. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, that is the sequence of intervals. The intervals are shrinking in size to 0-size so $P[X_n=1]\rightarrow 0$ and $P[X_n=0]\rightarrow 1$ (as would be the case for any other sequence of intervals with size that goes to zero). The intervals are arranged like this to ensure prob 1 convergence is impossible.

Comment: Note that **convergence with probability 1** is also called **convergence almost surely.**  This is different from the much weaker type of convergence called **convergence in probability**. You have a textbook example of a random process $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that converges to 0 in probability, but not with probability 1.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to say for  sure what $X_5,X_6...$ are, but this looks like a standard example of  sequence which convreges in measure but not almost surely. So my guess is $(X_n)$ is the sequence obtained by arranging the functions $I_{[\frac {i-1} {2^{n}},\frac i {2^{n}})}$ in  sequence with increasing  order of the denominator $2^{n}$ and increasing order of $i$ within each block. In that case $EX_n$ is the sequence $(\frac 1 2,\frac 1 2, \frac 1 4,\frac 1 4 ,\frac 1 4,\frac 1 4,...)$ where $\frac 1 {2^{n}}$ is repeated $2^{n}$ times. Hence $EX_n \to 0$ which means $X_n \to 0$ in $L^{1}$. The sequence does not converge almost surely because, at every point, there are infinitely many $0$'s and $1$'s.

Comment: So the idea is that each interval becomes of measure zero as gets larger so that the lim of $E[X_n]= 0$ but the sequence of andom variable keeps depending on N as N gets larger, so that it does not converge a.s to any random variable, not only to 0. Actually $P(w:X_n(w)=0)=0\neq1$. Am I right?

Comment: @LearningProb Yes, what you have written is correct.

Comment: @LearningProb : Actually, in this example we have $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[\omega: X_n(\omega)=0]=1$$ So $X_n$ converges to 0 in probability, and in mean square, and in L1, but not with probability 1.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170559/convergence-types-in-probability-theory-counterexamples/1170661 according to this there is a.s covergence so we can not have that limit to be one

Comment: So, do we have convergence in L1 or not?

Comment: Yes: compute the $L^1$ norm : it clearly goes to zero. So you have convergence in $L^1$ to the variable $0$.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say do we have A.S. convergence? This is not clear since we have two conflicting answers

Comment: @Michael claims that \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[\omega: X_n(\omega)=0]=1 implying $X_n$ converges a.s., while Kabo claims that this is not the case.

Comment: There is no disagreement between Kabo's answer and my comments.  We are both saying the same thing (to emphasize that, I have now +1'd Kabo's answer, which I neglected to do before).   Kabo incorrectly wrote a comment "yes what you have written is correct" in response to an (incorrect) suggestion that $P[\omega : X_n(\omega)=0]=0$. But that was likely only because Kabo did not read the last sentence fully.

Comment: The fact that $P[X_n=0]\rightarrow 1$ shows: (i) The LearningProb assertion $P[X_n=0]=0$ for all $n$ is  false; (ii) $X_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability.  It does not imply that $X_n\rightarrow 0$ with probability 1.  For that you need to evaluate $$P\left[\omega : \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n(\omega) = 0\right]$$ which is not the same thing as $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[\omega : X_n(\omega)=0]$.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying